# C Global Variable Code giving an compilation error

Tags: c

So I'm new to c and wrote some code but i'm not sure why i'm getting an error when i try to run it.

```
 int GlobalVariable=0;
int main()
{
    int LocalVariable=0;  //can be used within main()
    dis();
    printf(GlobalVariable);
    return 1;
}

int dis()
{
    GlobalVariable=5;  //Can be accessed in any functions and made changes to it
}
```

Comment: include declarations/protype functions in a header *.h file not with your source code.  if you want a global variable use something like misc.h {  extern int global_variable;  /* blah blah blah description of variable */  }  in your source file  #include "misc.h"  int global_variable = 37;  pass around the include to other source files.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to put the complete error message in your question.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", GlobalVariable);` to print it.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off learning/asking about *the error message*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the prototype of printf function:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

And look what you are typing:

```
int GlobalVariable=0;
printf(GlobalVariable);
```

Comment: The code changes the `GlobalVariable` to 5 before calling `printf`, but yes, this is the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you used a function without first telling the compiler about it.

In this case you must provide function prototype as the function definition itself is provided after `main`

```
int dis( void ); // function prototype
int main()
{
    ...
}
int dis() // function definition
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can put the function definition before `main()`. But usually it would be better to have function prototypes before `main()` and  (usually) even better to put the prototypes in a separate header file - that way it'd be easier to look straight into the main program without being bother about other function details.

Comment: since this is `C` you should use the declaration `int dis(void);` to indicate `dis` takes no arguments.

Comment: @user3386109 "he problem has nothing to do with the missing function prototype"? without the prototype it won't even compile

Comment: @user3386109 I overlooked that printf thing (that has been answered) - but surely the prototype is relevant - not sure why you suggested otherwise

Comment: C89 will assume a declaration for `dis` that matches so in that case it's surprisingly valid, and most compilers in a post-C89 mode will only issue a warning.

Comment: @artm [it's a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b941b7279ab41a53) which is worth calling out, but it's not  invalid code. But the `int dis(void);` vs `int dis()` is a [real thing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d05dc3dfee23f706) you should change.

Comment: @RyanHaining ok I see why the flag I used is `-pedantic-errors` - that's why it's an error

Comment: @artm only in C99 and up though, with `-std=c89` it isn't an extension it's part of the language so it's [not a pedantic error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daac5a4dbc0cc5d8)

Comment: @RyanHaining thanks for pointing that `int dis(void)` to ensure function must not accept any param. Also it was actually an warning not error without that  `-pedantic-errors` gcc flag as seen on my machine

Comment: I can see now why you had a different view of the problem. For the record, when I compiled the code it compiled with 5 warnings without the function prototype, and with 4 warnings with the function prototype. So the missing function prototype seemed like the least of the problems to me, especially since no arguments are passed to that function, and the return value from the function is not used.

Comment: @user3386109 haha and that's why i saw that first error coming up to my face as "implicit declaration.." error that I completely ignore to look down to the printf line..